# Waring's problem for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Probably a well-know question, but I haven't solved it, so I'll ask.

I can show that every matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the sum of two squares of matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.
If $n>2$, I can also show that every matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the sum of three squares of matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

So my question is : Is every matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the sum of two squares of matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (n>2)?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, every matrix is the average of two unitaries (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix#Properties). 

Comment: That sounds wrong to me.  The set of unitary n by n matrices is compact, so the set of averages of two unitary matrices is compact too.  So the latter set cannot equal the space of all n by n matrices.

Comment: Wikipedia missed the requirement that the norm of the matrix should be ≤ 1.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Comment: @Steve: two still sounds suspicious. Every matrix (in fact, every element of a C*-algebra) is  a linear combination of four unitaries, by a standard trick. Perhaps the wikipedia entry is assuming that the matrix is self-adjoint? (the proof of the 4-unitary result goes via this special case)

Comment: One remark: Waring's problem usually takes place in the context of integers, not real numbers.  So one might ask:  what can one say about sums of squares of nxn matrices?  Here there is a nice story,having to do with Siegel modular forms and powers of the Siegel theta function; see e.g. A.N.Andrianov's book "Quadratic forms and Hecke operators."

Comment: On a related topic, someone posted a problem in sci.math.research about 10 years ago: What matrices are expressible as the sum of invertible matrices?  That problem solves easily, but there is an interesting twist: what matrices are expressible as the sum of exactly two invertible matrices?  David Radcliffe and I found only one exception among all nxn matrices over many rings R where R belongs to a large class of rings that includes all fields.  This result might interest the original poster.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.04.10

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is YES if $n$ is even.  But if $n$ is odd, then the answer is NO since $-I$ is not a sum of two squares.
See

Griffin and Krusemeyer, Matrices as sums of squares, *Linear and Multilinear Algebra* **5** (1977/78), no. 1, 33-44

for the proofs of these facts and generalizations.